# Persist state using ngrx effect AFTER reducer processing

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In my Angular/ngrx app, I'm managing data persistence in indexeddb using @Effect.

```
  @Effect() updateObj$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(MyActions.UPDATE_OBJ)
  .switchMap( payload => this.storage.set('obj', payload.rawObj));
```

But this is not what I want: 
I don't want to persist the raw object from payload, 
but object transformed by my reducer logic 
(which is in fact the result state).

Every examples I've seen are very basic so data can be persisted as-is from payload.

I could put this logic in my controller but I don't think it's the redux way to achieve this.

Could you tell me a better way?

Comment: If you want to persist ngrx store (result of reducers...) you could take a look into: https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the latest state by using the .withLatestFrom operator.

```
@Effect() updateObj$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(MyActions.UPDATE_OBJ)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(<your-state-selector-goes-here>))
    .switchMap( ([action, state]) => ....);
```

[Official .withLatestFrom docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom)

[Simplified docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html)

Since the effect is triggered by an action dispatch, the state you will receive will be the result state (returned by your reducer handling the UPDATE_OBJ action).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way with NGRX 4 it gives me error _effect dispatched an invalid action_, so I had to add map operator  `.withLatestFrom(this.store.select('xxx'))
    .map (([action, state]) => ({type: action.type, payload: state})).switchMap(action =>`